# systemd-analyze blame

Tags: systemd, lvm, networkmanager

I use Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon (upgraded from 17).

I try to comprehend, why my Haswell CPU with 16GB RAM and 500GB SSD is booting longer than expected.

When I run:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

The first two lines look suspicious:

> ```
> 8.080s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
> 1.039s lvm2-monitor.service
> ```

1. I don't use LVM that I know of, can I safely uninstall `lvm2` package?
2. Why would the Network Manager need to wait for 8 seconds when connected to LAN.

---

Could anyone shed a light on this issue?

Comment: ``systemctl disable lvm2-monitor``. Do you use DHCP?

Comment: @user996142 I do use DHCP, does that slow it down?

Comment: Could be.  Can you check logs (like ``journalctl`` or ``/var/log``) for anything strange? ``NetworkManager`` uses the '``daemon``' syslog facility, configure your ``syslog`` to check it. I am sure it should be DHCP or DNS registration issue.

Comment: On my Linux mint, I completely eliminated the 8 second *NetworkManager-wait-online.service* delay. Run `systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online`, then go into the *Menu* and search for *Startup*. In the *Startup* menu, create a new *custom* entry with the command line `/bin/bash -c "/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager-wait-online restart &"`. Enjoy :). NOTE: this only shows the desktop sooner. You wont have internet until the NetworkManager loads. If trying this breaks the internet, then run `systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online&&systemctl start NetworkManager-wait-online` to undo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LVM2 package can usually be disabled.

```
systemctl disable lvm2-monitor
```

as root user.

The network problem is more interesting. If you (want to) use the network manager, you probably use DHCP. Depending on your network and especially on your DHCP server (usually the router), the time necessary to connect may vary and may be even in the range of 8 seconds.

8 seconds are indeed a long time, at least for a private network, but it's usually no problem at your computer.

By the way, restart your computer some times, and check if the time is always that large.